# deploying elasticsearch with docker

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I'm new to deploying with docker and elasticsearch.

I followed the curriculum here http://prakhar.me/docker-curriculum/#docker-aws, but I do not understand how the data is maintained if we downloaded and pushed a base ES image.

When I deploy my ES service, I'd like to keep the documents that are currently on it so I don't have to bulk create again.

How do you transfer data along with the elasticsearch service with docker?
I have pulled the base ES image but am unsure how I can configure my docker file.

Comment: Sounds like you need a persistent data location. You could mount a volume into the container or make a separate data container. There a examples on [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/)

Comment: okay got it! I''m there now. I'll start on it